# String.prototype.includes() returns true when it shouldn't

Tags: javascript

Recently while solving some coding problems I ran into a weird situation where i had to check if:
String starts with another string

I solved it quite simply with

```js
if(string.includes(substring))
{
 //code
}
```

And it worked..... BUT it returned **TRUE** when:

```js
const string = "is it you or is it me or what?";
const substring = "is it me or";
```

What is the reason behind this returning true?
I even tried on different compiler websites and they all returned true. I really am puzzled as my understanding of .includes() is that it should check if a string contains the sub-string.

EDIT: I'm actually blind and i didn't notice that it contains the same string in middle of the sentence. Sorry, didn't have much sleep.

Comment: shouldn't your code example say `string.includes`?

Comment: Yes thank you @tromgy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only need to return true if string **starts** with substring, use `.startsWith()` instead. For example:

```
> 'abc'.startsWith('a')
true

> 'abc'.startsWith('b')
false
```

Both `.contains()` (deprecated now, but might be supplied by polyfill) and `.includes()` (supported universally), however, will return true in both cases, as it checks whether or not a substring is *contained* within a given string, not necessarily at its beginning:

```
> 'abc'.includes('a')
true
> 'abc'.includes('b')
true
```

To answer your specific question, `is it me or` is part of that bigger string. You can use `.indexOf()` as a little helper here to provide you the exact position of that string:

```
const string = "is it you or is it me or what?";
const substring = "is it me or";
string.indexOf(substring); // 13
```

Comment: Thanks, didn't think about using this and also didn't notice the second appearence in the middle of the string i said.